# Oracle SQL Developer - Create Function Using Script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

**[Explanation]**
If I want to create a function which belongs to schema 'A', It is my understanding that I need to create package in schema 'A', and implement function. (Please correct me if there is another way to do this).
If I am trying to create a function using script files **(example. New Gallery -> SQL Files (Database Files) to create untitled.sql)**, I am getting confused because that function does not belong to any schema and it will be stored in Global.

**[Question]**
1) How to create function belongs to schema 'A' using script?
2) The function stored in global cannot access to schema table, how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: IMO using GUI is not a sustainable solution. Instead write a function code with your favorite text editor; save the file as a plain text file into version control system; run/execute the file into a database from command line with SQL*Plus. A GUI is great for reading database but never create/modify PL/SQL code directly in a database with GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I totally agree with Ascalonian. For the sake of your question, I will provide instructions on how to create a function using the SQL Developer's GUI tools and this will generate a script.

In many ways, I would rather use SQL*Plus. For the sake of my example, I will use the standard Oracle example schema, SCOTT.

**Question 1:   How to Create a Function Using Script**

*note: I show how to create this function using the GUI tools in SQL Developer and they generate a script*

If you are logged in to database user, SCOTT, just right click on user SCOTT’s functions and select “New Function”

[image]

A “Create Function” dialog box will open.
[image]

You just modify the name to correspond with your naming convention and your project.  Choose your option and select OK.
Next in the code editor, modify the function more to suit your needs:
[image]

Here is my final draft.  Select ‘Compile’:
 [image]

Now it displays and shows as a function object owned by SCOTT. The GUI tool generates a script function without qualifying SCOTT's ownership. If there is no qualifying, the function by default is owned by SCOTT.                                    :

[image]

If I invoke this function in a SQL Developer worksheet logged in as SCOTT, we see it here:
 [image]

In general, if you want to share an object with all users, the standard approach is to grant execute to public or create a public synonym. Here is an example of granting execute to public:

[image]

You can then check you privileges with other users:

[image]

In general, using this GUI 
tool is nice and helps you get the right syntax.  After awhile you will probably abandon this (rather slow and cumbersome).

**Question 2:  The function stored in global cannot access to schema table, how do I fix it?**

There are many ways to address how to grant select access on a table.

With my example, one could grant select on the table to the function owner, SCOTT.

You could do this like this:

`GRANT SELECT ON OTHER_SCHEMA.PRECIOUS_TABLE TO SCOTT;`

Another common approach might be to grant the system privilege, SELECT ANY TABLE, to SCOTT.  Of course, security should always be considered and the principle of granting the least amount of privilege to accomplish a task should be adhered to.

Comment: Quick question. The type of return value for my function would be something else (not Varchar or number), so that I need to implement 
"create or replace type My_Return_Type as object". How do I include in that worksheet?

Comment: The GUI does not expose all object types owned by the schema owner, thus you would need to do this without the GUI.  I would create your object type in the schema you wish to use it and then you can declare your function with that object return type.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use a package to create a function. Functions can be stand-alone objects.

A script to create a Function can be found by reading the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm) on how to create functions.

To create it in a specific schema, just add the schema name to the function name OR log in as that other user.

**Note:** If you are to create a function in another schema, you need to have the *CREATE ANY PROCEDURE* privilege.

Comment: I appreciate for your help! If possible, will you be able to explain me more about 'CREATE ANY PROCEDURE privilege'?

Comment: It is a privilege granted to your user account by yourself of a DBA, depending on your rights/privileges in your database. You would need to be granted that before you can create the function in another Schema.